# How can I get particular webpage using jquery or Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two .cshtml webforms, in one webform I have Bootstrap header and in other webform I have one div containg form. Now I want to implement such thing like when I click any of links available in Header that time Jquery function will be called and it should get desired page and load it into defined div block.

My code is seems as bellow (header.cshtml) :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assest/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(str) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert(str);
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: str + ".cshtml",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#form_load").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })


        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="nav_link" onclick="myFunction(this.name)" name="farmer_master">Farmer</a>
</div>
<div id="form_load"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

other webform (farmer_master.cshtml) :

```
<div>
 Hi I shoud be called !
</div>
```

Comment: As long as you don't have .cshtml in link you can't call bare file directly. You have to call action in controller which will return the view.

Comment: The moment for document ready to fire has long passed by the time your function is called. Nesting them into each other this way does not make sense. Using the old-school way of attaching event handlers via onclick attribute the ajax call does not even need to be inside document ready. However, you should try up-to-date event binding, meaning jquery's .on method.